# Подготовленные запросы в PHP при использовании PDO sqlsrv (MSSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

Переношу с MYSQL в MSSQL проект.
Столкнулся с проблемой в подготовленных запросах.
Если раньше я использовал в MYSQL

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 as something,
                                        t.id,
                                        creator_id,
                                        status,
                                        fire,
                                        u.firstname as firstname,
                                        u.surname as surname,
                                        category,
                                        responsible,
                                        t.dept,
                                      FROM tickets as t LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u ON t.responsible = u.id
                                        WHERE creator_id = :uid AND status = 'Статус 1'
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT 2 as something,
                                        t.id,
                                        creator_id,
                                        status,
                                        fire,
                                        u.firstname as firstname,
                                        u.surname as surname,
                                        category,
                                        responsible,
                                        t.dept,
                                        FROM tickets as t LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u ON t.responsible = u.id
                                        WHERE creator_id = :uid AND (status = 'Статус 2' OR status = 'Статус 3' OR status = 'Статус 4')
                                        ");
```

$stmt->bindParam(':uid',$uid,PDO::PARAM_INT);

Все было хорошо.

Но в ситуации с MSSQL отрабатывает только обычный query если подставить значения вручную, а при prepare выбрасывается ошибка:
**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error in ... line 806**

*Причем, заметил что если не использовать UNION, то ошибок нет. Оставляю только первый SELECT и ошибок нет.

Буду рад, если у кого-нибудь есть опыт как обойти такую неприятную вещь.

Answer (score 2):

В mysql, если отключить режим эмуляции, была бы та же самая ошибка.

В нативном режиме [одинаковые имена плейсхолдеров не поддерживаются](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation). Так что надо делать два разных плейсхолдера и биндить их тоже два раза, с одним и там же значением.

Comment: bingo! Большое спасибо, очень разрулили.